# if statement with DataBinder.Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

the code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="height: 1px; width: 100%; " align="center">
    <div style="height: 1px; width: 90%; background-color: #cccccc;"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
       <% if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productID").ToString() == "32668" || DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productID").ToString() == "33829" || DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productID").ToString() == "33831")
          { %>

    <tr>
      <td style="height: 132px; width: 25%; padding-left:20px;"><a href='product_detail_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productID")%>.aspx'> <img src='<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductImageUrl"] %>t_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductImg")%>'
                                        border="0" /></a> </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><br>
        <a href='product_detail_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productID")%>.aspx'> <font color="#000000"><b> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductName")%> </b></font></a> <br />
        <br />
        <span class="detailSpan"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shortDesc")%> </span></td>
      <td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b> <%# WebDirectBrands.Utility.FormatNumber(Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductPrice")))%> </b> <br />
        <br />
        <a href='product_detail_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productID")%>.aspx'> <img src="images/Details-Link.gif" border="0" /></a> <br />
        <a href='add_to_cart.aspx?productid=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productID")%>'> <img src="images/AddtoCart-Link.gif" border="0" style="margin-top: 5px;" /></a> </td>
    </tr>
      <% } %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" height="15px"></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

So I have like 40 items, and I want to show just 3 in Featured products.  I wanted to use if statement and operator || but the problem is DataBinder.Eval .I did't find answer that can help me.  Can someone help me?  Is there some shorter solution with  "short if "(a == c ? b : c)  or some solution wihtout asp:repeater :)

Comment: You can't use inline blocks in repeaters in the same way you do with normal mark-up, they simply don't work.  The only inline blocks you can use with repeaters are `<%# %>` and `<%#: %>`.  You'd be better off filtering the data you're giving to the repeater, rather than asking the repeater to ignore the things you don't want to see

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the data before binding to the repeater will be the optimal solution.
However you could subscribe to the ItemDataBound event and decide to hide or display the particular item on the fly.

[See this link on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In the event handler you can then probably do

```
e.Item.Visible = false;
```